# Did USA share Moon rocks with other countries on a permanent basis?

Tags: the-moon

USA got some 400 kg of Moon rocks with Apollo program.

Did they share rocks with other countries in form of *permanent* gifts?

If yes, then which countries got such gift, and what information about their locations in recent times is available?

Comment: You ask a lot of questions that can be answered by one google search, but this one is particularly egregious. Note that the tooltip on upvoting a question says *This question shows research effort* And downvotes show *This question does not show any research effort* Downvoted for zero research effort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_rock#Goodwill_Moon_rocks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Did USA share Moon rocks with other countries on a permanent basis?

Yes.

There were both loans and gifts; more than a Stack Exchange answer can properly cover.

So for details see the December 8, 2011 Office of Audits report **NASA’s Management of Moon Rocks and Other Astomaterials Loans for Research, Education, and Public Display** REPORT No. IG-12-007 (Assignment No. A-11-015-00)

- https://oig.nasa.gov/audits/reports/FY12/IG-12-007.pdf